# User registration form not display -User Submitted Form plugin - wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, plugins

I have created my own theme in WordPress and now I have installed User Submitted Post plugin , to set forms for front-end users.But this forms are not appearing . What is I am doing wrong ?

May be I have missed something during Theme Programming ? Does WordPress have any feature in `php` that allows submit forms to appear in front-end ?

Please help/suggest me to solve my issue.

Comment: There must be a short code which is used to display form at front-side please refer plugin's documentation.

Comment: I have set the shortcode but nothing appears.

Comment: Share your code

Comment: which part of code to share?

Comment: I think I have forgot to set any feature in functions.php that is connected with plugin

Comment: which short-code you have used and which plugin?

Comment: The plugin is User Submitted Form and the shortcode is [user-submitted-posts]

Comment: It is not just with User Submitted Post, the same thing happens with any plugin that have to show submit form in frontend .

Comment: maybe there is any function to let these plugins to appear in frontend.

Comment: try this <?php if (function_exists('user_submitted_posts')) user_submitted_posts(); ?>

Comment: yes. it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using

```
 <?php if (function_exists('user_submitted_posts')) user_submitted_posts(); ?>
```

It will work.